# Arduino Servo MG90S not moving

Tags: arduino-nano, servo

[image]I'm new with arduino (nano). I am having problems with Servo MG90S, I cant make it move. Im doing the easiest test, Servo cables connected:

Brown -> gnd
Red -> 5v
Orange -> pin 9

my arduino code is:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo;

const int servoPin = 9;

void setup()
{
  servo.attach(servoPin);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{ 
  servo.write(40);
  delay(2000);
  servo.write(0);
  delay(2000);
}
```

As you see its a super simple example, but the result is the servo vibrating slightly.

Extra data: the servo start vibrating with the `servo.attach(servoPin);` it doesnt matters if I set the `servo.write(40);`

Comment: The parameter of `Servo.write()` is a value between 0 and 180, so -40 is not valid. Does is change something if you use 50 and 130 instead?

Comment: No, the same result. Even if I only set the attach without the servo.write the servo is vibrating with no stop. I don't know if that is a normal behavior

Comment: Arduino power source is one of the most common problems.  For example a 9 Volt battery may run an Arduino but is unlikely to have enough power to run a motor.  What are you using as a power source?

Comment: Also, if you change your code please edit the question to reflect the change.

Comment: As I'm in developing procces, im using the mini usb wire that goes to my desktop pc usb 3.0 port

Comment: Did you connect the servo to Arduino GND *AND* the USB port? That may be your problem. Nowhere does it say that. You just said "Brown -> gnd." That doesn't mean so.

Comment: Also, you may be connecting it to just the Arduino, and that could be the problem, too. As usually all Arduino have very little current.

Comment: Wait, so... what is the USB connected to? The servo? May you, please, provide more detail? I could give an answer, but I am not sure what the *EXACT* problem is.

Comment: I edited the post and added an image of how it tis connected, all is conected to protoboard and this to the arduino (in my cade arduino nano), the USB wire is the one who power de arduino board, and goes from my pc USB port

Comment: Okay... try this: use a separate *5V* power supply for your servo. Connecting the red to the positive of the power supply, and black to the GND of the power supply. Let me, then, know if it's still twitching. That may be your problem.

Comment: Also, what model is the servo? Like, what is the name of it? It depends of why it is twitching. If it's a micro servo, it would *SHOULD* be fine. Just Google what you have and post what it is. The more details, the better.

Comment: Also, remember: Google is your best friend, in this case.

Comment: I compiled the code, it works. So, there seems to be an issue with the hardware. I am trying to decipher between the two: it's either your Arduino Nano or the servo itself. Or *POSSIBLY* both.

Comment: Oh, and I DID use the same exact wiring.

Comment: Oh, right. I didn't read. Sorry. The model of the servo is MG90S. I will read the datasheet on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here is the deal: I have looked up the datasheet for the Arduino Nano and the MG90S. The problem is: you may have killed your Arduino Nano. As the datasheet for the Arduino Nano says, "Max DC Current per I/O Pin... 40 mA." ([The Datasheet for Arduino Nano](https://diyi0t.com/arduino-nano-tutorial/)). I am not sure if that's 100% of the issue, so, then I looked up the MG90S and it says "Current (typical during movement)... 120-250mA" ([Also, another datasheet](https://protosupplies.com/product/servo-motor-micro-mg90s-continuous-rotation/)). Basically, all that means is that you *MAY* have to buy another Arduino because you may have used a servo that requires to much (for lack of a better term) "power." Using some math we see that you went approximately: 210 milli-amps over. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so my first answer is WRONG. The reason being is because the MG90S and the SG90 (which are very similar servos, except the gearing and some others) **CAN** run off that Arduino. As this article shows: [How to control the MG90S with the Nano](https://www.hibit.dev/posts/101/how-to-control-servo-motor-with-arduino). However, it *IS* best to run that servo off a separate power supply (5V). The issue lies within your wiring. Somehow, there is some miscommunication between us, you, and the Arduino.

Comment: I have tested the output voltage
5v pin -> 4.6v 
pin 9 with servo.write(0) -> 0.13v
pin 9 with servo.write(180) -> 0.56v

I don't know if these are acceptable values.

Comment: Do you know what I mean by "separate power supply?" I think you need some time to reflect. You seem to steadily *NOT* want to use another source for your servo. Why? I told you the answer, gave you an article, and even asked, kindly, for more details. What more do you want from me?

Comment: That article gives the **EXACT** instructions. *Edit - please edit your response with more detail, as I still can't seem to help you (which I really do).

Comment: Honestly, I think I am starting to second guess myself on my first answer. I will post it for your sake. I think you BURNT your Arduino. Outputting those results, they seem terrible. So, yeah, I think you BURNT your Arduino.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize there were two answers cause they appeared together and I only saw one. I think the other one is okey.
Thank you for taking your time to help.

Comment: Well, like I said, the first answer (that you accepted ) is flat out wrong. That was my assumption. But I am okay as long as you are okay, with the answer, of course. And sorry, if I came across as a jerk or frustrated. That was not the intention. Hope your project goes well, though! I just want you to learn about this Googling thing. Again, sorry.